# ASP Classic, getting just the data from datetime from a database query

Tags: database, date, datetime, asp-classic

Ive looked around Google and can't find any working code. I want to query my database to return just results from a certain date. But the datetime column in my database has both the Date and the Time.

How would I go about doing this.

today = 15/08/2013

An example of one of the database values = 15/08/2013 02:13:18 PM

And here is my code at the moment

```
'Connect to database
set conn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Provider="Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
conn.Open Server.MapPath("/nightclub_photography/data/database/jamsnaps.mdb")

'Get the current date
today = Request.Cookies("sdate")
response.write today

sql = "SELECT * FROM sales WHERE saleDate =" & today

Set rs = conn.Execute(sql)

if rs.EOF then
    response.write "Error!"
end if
```

Answer (score 1):

Dates are passed as strings. Wrap them in single quotes.

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM sales WHERE saleDate = '" & today & "'"
```

Comment: I got told by someone to pass them INTO the database like so:
#15/08/2013 02:13:18 PM#.

Comment: That would only match that specific time. You can also use saleDate  >= '15/08/2013 00:00:00' and saleDate <= '15/08/2013 23:59:59'

Comment: SELECT * FROM sales WHERE saleDate >= '15/08/2013 00:00:00' AND saleDate <= '15/08/2013 00:00:00'. Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

Comment: Hmm, just found some code I used somewhere else. DATEVALUE(column).

Comment: Is the DB field a date field or a text field with dates in it?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I used this in some other code which seemed to work.

DATEVALUE(columnName)

Answer (score 0):

If you know that `today` consists of only the date, you could concatenate the time and do something like this:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM sales WHERE saleDate >= '" & today & " 00:00:00' AND today <= '" & today  & " 23:59:59'"
```

You could use one of VBScript's date functions to guarantee the contents of `today` are only the date if you want to be sure. Something like:

```
today = FormatDateTime(today,vbShortDate)
```